# Can one design fast non-Cartesian Fourier transforms sampled on a cartesian grid in several dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, computational-mathematics

**Background:** The Fourier Transform is - at least partly due to its factorizable nature (FFT) - arguably one of the most impactful integral transforms in science and engineering.

When performing a Fourier Transform on signals of more than one dimension, what is commonly done is to utilize the separability of the transform on a Cartesian grid. This way it conveniently becomes possible to perform the whole multidimensional FFT as a sequence of one-dimensional FFTs - one along each dimension.

However this only works on ON coordinate systems, in other words Cartesian grids. What happens if we want to perform on some other coordinate system - for example a polar coordinate system:

[image]
[image]

Example of basis functions on a polar grid in 2D.

Can we still derive a way to use the speed-ups provided by a FFT factorization ?

**Clarification** : my signal is still sampled on a Cartesian grid like a computer bitmap image is, but the Fourier basis functions should be separable like $\exp(-2\pi i r) \exp(-2\pi i \theta)$ with origo in the middle of the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a sequence of one-dimensional FFT's: one along each dimension".  That could work if you're taking the Fourier transform of a function that happens to be a product of functions of each coordinate.  There's nothing particularly "cartesian" about this: in the case of polar coordinates you could have a function of the form $f(r) g(\theta)$.

Comment: Yes such basis functions are what I tried to depict the real part of : cosines in $r$ and second is cosines in $\theta$. My question relates to how I efficiently could compute it like a FFT. The pixel values will still lie on cartesian coordinates but the transform will be in polar coordinates. Hmm I should explain this more clearly.